# how to apply Gridview with fixrows and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I want to implemented gridview with three rows and multiple column. I tried below code but not able to achieve what i want.

my xml file is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="385dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        </GridView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and activity file code is

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,id_list,favflag_list,thumb_img_list));
    gridView.setNumColumns(5);
```

is it achievable or any other way

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

Binding Adapter :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
            R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
            R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
            R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
            R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
            R.drawable.pic_15
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Main Activity :

```
public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried above code. remaining image goes outof screen but scroll bar is not shown...why?

Comment: ya i also tried with that...put scroll not shown and images are also not move horizontally...

Answer (score 0):

it is depend on your data. if you add more data it will change its size. Example. if you have 9 picture to store in gridview. you must to set `android:numColumns = "3"` in xml, it will show you 3 rows.

Comment: actually i want only 3 rows and no of columns are change dynamically...so how to achive that...can you please explain with some code...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/gridview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:numColumns="auto_fit"
 android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
 android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
 android:columnWidth="90dp"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
 android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Custom xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imagepart"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textpart"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity :

```
public class CustomGridView extends Activity {

 // references to our images
 private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
   R.drawable.androider_01,
   R.drawable.androider_02,
   R.drawable.androider_03,
   R.drawable.androider_04,
   R.drawable.androider_05,
   R.drawable.androider_06,
   R.drawable.androider_07,
   R.drawable.androider_08,
   R.drawable.androider_09,
   R.drawable.androider_10,
   R.drawable.androider_11,
   R.drawable.androider_12,
   R.drawable.androider_13,
   R.drawable.androider_14,
   R.drawable.androider_15,
   R.drawable.androider_16
   };

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private Context mContext;

  public MyAdapter(Context c) {
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   mContext = c;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return mThumbIds.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return mThumbIds[arg0];
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return arg0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   View grid;

   if(convertView==null){
    grid = new View(mContext);
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygrid, parent, false);
   }else{
    grid = (View)convertView;
   }

   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
   TextView textView = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.textpart);
   imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
   textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

   return grid;
  }

 }

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    }
}
```